# TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined

Tags: angular, npm

I am new to Angular, I was trying to use localStorage API in my app.Whenever I run the application it throws an error `TypeError: localStorage.getItems is not a function` in console. Then after I downloaded `angular-local-storage` by help of [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-local-storage).I also imported `LocalStorageModule` in `app.module.ts` and added it to imports array.But,Now It throws this error:

```
angular-localstorage.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined
at TEST (angular-localstorage.js:24)
at eval (angular-localstorage.js:198)
at Object.../../../../angular-localstorage/angular-localstorage.js (vendor.bundle.js:206)
at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
at eval (index.js:1)
at Object.../../../../angular-localstorage/index.js (vendor.bundle.js:213)
at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
at eval (app.module.ts:7)
at Object.../../../../../src/app/app.module.ts (main.bundle.js:36)
at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)<br/>
```

Code containig getItem function:

```
    export class Init{
    load(){
        if(localStorage.getItem('markers')===null || localStorage.getItem('markers')===undefined)
        {
            console.log('No markers found...creating...');

            var markers=[

  {
    name:'Company One',
    lat:42.825588,
    lng:-71.018029,
    draggable:true
  },
 {
    name:'Company Two',
    lat:42.868170,
    lng:-70.889071,
    draggable:false
  },
  {
    name:'Company Three',
    lat:42.858279,
    lng:-71.930498,
    draggable:true
  }
  ];
        localStorage.setItem('markers',JSON.stringify(markers));


        }
        else
        {
            console.log('Loading markers...')
        }
    }
}
```

Code in app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {MarkerService} from './services/marker.service';
import {LocalStorageModule} from 'angular-localstorage';
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    LocalStorageModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey:''
    })
  ],
  providers: [MarkerService],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Can anyone help me out with this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Post your code, the bit with the getItems() and the app.module - that would help people help you.

Comment: I have added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localstorage` API is inbuilt into the Angular framework you won't need an external library for that. You can use it by `localStorage.<yourMethodName>` directly into your code

Also, there isn't any method called `getItems`.

The list of available methods are...

`getItem
removeItem
setItem
clear`

[More Info Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Actually I made a typo in a class which was inheriting the code which I have posted here.

Answer (score 1):

The standard localStorage API should work alright, no need to install module for that, use the usual way to get and set items in localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('name', 'ABC');
localStorage.getItem('name');
```

Comment: Look at my answer, you don't need a separate module angular-local-storage. The standard API should do the job for you.

Comment: Removing `angular-local-storage` gives error:`TypeError: localStorage.getItems is not a function`

Comment: you will need to add "dom" to the "lib" array in your tsconfig.json.